# What is the difference between SQL Server administrators and sysadmin/serveradmin?

Tags: sql, admin, sql-server-2014

After setting up a new SQL Server 2014 instance, my boss told me I forgot to add an account during the Account Provisioning section of the installation.

My user is a sysadmin, but not serveradmin.  What exactly is the difference?

Comment: administrators are people and the other two are database roles.

Comment: So if I add myself to the account provisioning section, will I also be added as a server role user?

Answer (score 0):

With sysadmin, you can control the server and with serveradmin, you can change setting, shutdown, alter resource etc.

So the members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform any activity in the server and Members of the serveradmin fixed server role can change server-wide configuration options and shut down the server.

For more information on rights, you can get from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx

Comment: These are the server-level roles;  I am wondering how a SQL Server Admin (set up at installation) relates to these server-level roles

Comment: Server level roles can be used for sharing database administration responsibilities among several logins.
So for example SYSADMIN is recommended for Senior administrators that can be trusted for configuring the server, creating and dropping users and databases.
and SERVERADMIN recommended for Database administrators in charge of configuring SQL Server for optimal performance.

You can look for good explanation at https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9764.built-in-server-roles-database-roles

Comment: So during installation, when I add provisioned accounts, that's the same as making the user a database-role serveradmin?

Comment: Yes additionally you can add more accounts later if you want to.

Comment: How?   Through security -> logins properties of DB?

Comment: Yes you can assign server roles to grant server security privileges to any db login/user.